# Can I offer my Namaz while wearing makeup?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, cosmetics

My question is about that can I offer prayer while wearing makeup and nail polish, or can I wear these in general? My classmate says that if I did my wudu before applying nail paint then I can offer Namaz, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not offer prayer by applying nail paint on your nails because it makes layer on the nails and prevent water from penetrating to the skin while ablution. if it is not permissible for ablution then how it is allowed for offering prayer. The best way is to remove nail paint from your nails and then offer prayer.

Comment: Your argument suggests that: since a woman has to remove her headscarf to perform wudu, how can something which has to be removed during wudu be allowed during prayers?

Comment: sorry, i am not talking about remove her headscarf to perform wudu what do you mean by that?

Comment: The premise of your statement is that _if something is not allowed during one act of worship, it is not allowed in another act of worship_. This is not true.